# Schema.org - Can Product be nested inside of CreativeWork to leverage extra facets?

Tags: microdata

It seems that [schema.org/Product](http://schema.org/Product) is a bit limited when it comes to pushing various attributes such as modified time. I see that [schema.org/CreativeWork](http://schema.org/CreativeWork) has an `about` facet that looks for a `Thing` (such as `Product`). Would it be an acceptable use case to nest `Product` inside the `CreativeWork` via `about`? Would the various graphs/clients/etc understand this? Has anyone attempted this technique or could share experiences?

Sample of this nesting using JSON-LD ([you can validate it here](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/)):

```
<script type="application/ld+json"> {
"@context" : "http://schema.org",
"@type" : "CreativeWork",
"datePublished" : "2014-05-15 12:41:39",
"dateModified" : "2015-01-15 10:45:18",
"creator" : {
    "@type" : "Organization",
    "name" : "A Huge Corporation"
},
"about" : {
    "@type" : "Product",
    "name" : "Pure Gold Widget",
    "image" : "http://example.com/product.jpg",
    "description" : "Various paragraphs of words",
    "model" : "PRD-010101",
    "productID" : "987747",
    "brand" : "A Rando Manufacturer",
    "aggregateRating" : {
        "@type" : "AggregateRating",
        "itemReviewed" : "Pure Gold Widget",
        "ratingValue" : "5",
        "ratingCount" : "8",
        "reviewCount" : "8"
    },
    "offers" : {
        "@type" : "Offer",
        "price" : "500",
        "priceCurrency" : "USD",
        "availability" : "http://schema.org/InStock",
        "seller" : "A Huge Corporation"
    }
}}
</script>
```

Bonus: I included an example of nesting organization within that too (albeit just a name field in this snippet). I am also unsure how nesting organization like this would make "the internets" react.

Comment: What exactly is the "modified time" about? Is it the time when the page (which is about a specific product, right?) was last modified?

Comment: @unor Correct, about a specific product, the time it was created and last time modified. There was a SaaS we used a while back...google always posted the date in the SERP for products (similar to how articles do it). It was nice since customers would see a degree of "freshness". I think they got their date ability from RSS, but i [hope] this would offer similar datapoint. Figured we could push some other CreativeWork flags as well with this nest style snippet, assuming it works as it seems. PS: I was wondering why schema.org is a syn for microdata tag...doesnt make much sense to me.

Comment: Hmm additional quick note about display of nested things in GWT structured data report: "The Structured Data page lists only the top-level entities discovered on a page. For example, if your page contains a schema.org/Event that in turn contains a schema.org/Place, only the Event item will be counted." This quote is found here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2650907?hl=en So i guess that means that if this were a "go" then GWT [currently] wouldnt show products since they would be nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having something like `CreativeWork → about → Product` seems to be appropriate: it’s a creative work whose "subject matter" is a product. However, you can be more specific:

[`ItemPage`](http://schema.org/ItemPage) inherits from `CreativeWork`:

> A page devoted to a single item, such as a particular product or hotel.

So you might want to use `ItemPage → about → Product`

Probably a better choice than [`about`](http://schema.org/about) would be a "main entity" property, which [gets discussed](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/301) currently.

Comment: After playing some with your answer i think its more valid than my angle. I don't know for sure if/how it passes into SERPs yet, but for now i will mark this as accepted. Thanks